# RichOutputText won't update programmatically

Tags: refresh, oracle-adf

I'm trying to do a simple 'Hello World' demo in ADF (Jdeveloper 12). I read a value from input, try to update a ADF RichOutputText (id ot1 in the sample) - but the page won't  update. The action code gets updated but not the UI. page snippet:

```
<f:view>
  <af:document title="hello.jspx" id="d1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.d1}">
      <af:form id="f1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.f1}">
          <af:decorativeBox id="db1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.db1}">
              <f:facet name="center"/>
              <f:facet name="top">
                  <af:outputText value="" id="ot1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.ot1}"/>
              </f:facet>
          </af:decorativeBox>
          <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.pgl1}">
              <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.pgl2}" halign="center"/>
          </af:panelGroupLayout>
          <af:inputText label="Your Name?" id="it1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.it1}"/>
          <af:button text="Go" id="b1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.b1}"
                     action="#{backingBeanScope.backing_hello.b1_action}"/>
      </af:form>
  </af:document>
```

bean method:

```
public String b1_action() {
    RichInputText inputText = getIt1(); 
    String name = "Hello "+(String)inputText.getValue()+ "!";
    System.out.println("This Is Entered "+name);
    ot1.setValue(name);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger partial page update, so UI can catch up with the state.

```
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(inputText);
```

Btw, you better switch to actionListener instead of action.

Comment: Thank you - this is not mentioned in any of the tutorials for hello world.